# Runtime error occurs while accessing elements of vector container

Tags: c++, vector

In the below mentioned program I am converting integer into vector, then the number is checked for divisibility by each element of vector. However, while accessing the vector elements to check for divisibility of the elements by number, runtime error occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int testcase;
cin>>testcase;  //number of testcases inputted
while(testcase--)
{
int number,i=0,count=0;
cin >>number;                //number is inputted
int p=number;
vector<int> arr(100);      
while(number){            //converting integer to array
    arr[i]=number%10;

    number=number/10;
    cout<<arr[i];
    if(p%arr[i]==0) //checking whether each element of array is divisible by number //this gives runtime error
    count++;
    i++;
}

  cout<<endl<<count<<endl; //printing the count of elemnts of array  divisible by number
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

I have commented out the if condition that is giving the runtime error(without the if condition, the program runs correctly). Can someone please tell me how it can be corrected?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition

```
if(p%arr[i]==0)
```

`arr[i]` can be equal to `0`.

Thus if the number contains 0 then the program will fail.

Comment: Somehow I forgot about mod 0 being illegal. Thanks a lot. Your suggestion helped me big time :)

Answer (score 0):

What if `number % 10 == 0` ?
This will mean that `arr[i] = 0`  and thus the expression `p%arr[i]` will result in Undefined Behaviour because `mod 0` is illegal. Your while loop should look something like `while(number % 10)`.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.However, I took inputs which are not multiple of 10 and I am still getting the same error.Is there anything else that is incorrect?

Comment: Seeing is believing.  Let us see the check for the condition that the value is not a multiple of 10 or that you are not doing a mod 0

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I put an if condition so that mod 0 does not occur. And that did the trick :) Thank you Jamey D and PaulMcKenzie